# Using the same actionBar switch for entire app

Tags: android

I have two activities, in each activity I need to set up an action bar switch to control sound like so...

```
        actionBarSwitch = new Switch(this);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarSwitch, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.END));
        actionBar.setTitle(title);
        actionBarSwitch.setText(sfx);
        actionBarSwitch.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.white));
        actionBarSwitch.setChecked(soundOn);
        actionBarSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

The hassle with this is, everytime I change activities, I need to pass the boolean value of whether or not the switch is checked, to the other activity. I'm getting errors and rather than dealing with them I think it will be A LOT easier if my whole application just shared one single switch in the actionbar so I dont have to keep track of its state. Is this possible?

EDIT: Im using shared preferences like so...

Set:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("soundOn", soundOn);
        prefs.edit().commit();
```

Recieve:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        soundOn = prefs.getBoolean("soundOn", true);
```

But it's not working, why?

Comment: you can have a shared preference and can save the value of `Boolean` and can retrieve in any of your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the states of the switch in `SharedPreferences`, when creating each `Activity` check the value in `SharedPreferences` and set the switch accordingly. That's probably the easiest way of doing what you are asking.

Comment: That is what im doing but its not working. So it would be easier if the whole application shared one switch in the action bar

Comment: That's not possible. If this doesn't work, you're doing something wrong, as this should work flawlessly.

Comment: Where in each activity is the code you posted for setting the value?

Comment: just before I call finish() I set it. Then I recieve it in the onResume() of the other activity. And I have checked and it IS being called. I used System.out.println() and I found out that the value is false when I set it but true when I recieve it...

Comment: One potential problem is that you call `edit()` again after you put your boolean in the shared preferences; I don't know what behavior this would cause but it's worth a check. Try `prefs.edit().putBoolean("soundOn", soundOn).commit();` instead of what you currently have.